# How do I fix a black screen at login in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, boot, system-installation, radeon, grub-efi

## Description of the problem

I am installing Ubuntu 14.04 LTS from a UEFI USB flash drive. When I boot from the flash drive, I get the installer menu e.g. "Try ubuntu without installing" etc.

It gets to the purple splash screen with the loading dots, then the screen goes black.

## Hardware specs

- Intel i7-4770k
- ASUS Maximus VI Formula
- MSI Radeon R9 390
- 16 GB RAM

My display is connected with HDMI directly to the MOBO, and it's also connected to the primary display on the GFX card.

## What I've done to troubleshoot

- I had Ubuntu installed previously, when I was using a different
  graphics card. Mobo wasn't recognizing at it some point so I reformatted
  that drive using Windows. One thing that might be causing my problems
  is that grub was never removed. I tried booting to the Windows disk
  and doing "repair install" as well as running the commands
  `bootrec/fixmbr` and `bootrec/fixboot` but it seems like grub is
  still installed somewhere. Not sure if that could be interfering with
  my installation.
- I've also tried running the installer with the `nomodeset` option.
  Hasn't really helped with the blackscreen issue. Not 100% sure if I'm
  doing it right, but when I get to the installer screen, I press e,
  add the option, and then press f10 (Ctrl doesn't work for some
  reason)
- Tried setting the display settings in the BIOS to only use the built
  in graphics.
- I updated my BIOS software, I think I might have had a version
  installed for the wrong chipset. (Flashed it a while ago when I was
  more nooby)

I still have my old graphics card, so I'm thinking I could put that one in, install Ubuntu and the appropriate driver for my new GFX card, then replace the GFX card with the new one. I'm just afraid this method will be a waste of time.

Edit:

I've made a custom boot option in /boot/grub/grub.cfg as follows. Hasn't worked yet though.

`menuentry "Custom install" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    set gfxmode=auto
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity quiet splash -- nomodeset nolapic acpi=off
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz

}`

Comment: +1 Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Thank you for taking the time to write such a nice, high quality and easy to read post!

Comment: Welcome and thanks from me as well. I just took the time to add a more descriptive title. There *should* be a question somewhere at least. ;) Feel free to tweak it a bit if you want to make it clearer.

Comment: Anyone have any insights on this? Tried 16.04 LTS today and had the same issue...